# Binary variable random slope in an HLM using R lmer

Tags: r, random-effects-model, lme4-nlme, multilevel-analysis

I want to look at whether a promotion the year prior has an effect on performance rating in the following year. I have been struggling with how to model this in R using the lme4 package. The data looks like this:

`> str(dataset)
'data.frame':   227163 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ Employee      : chr  "33816" "34863" "34863" "34863" ...
 $ Year          : int  1 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ...
 $ Performance   : num  -0.26 0.206 0.206 0.206 0.206 ...
 $ Prior.Yr.Promo: num  0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 ...`

`> head(dataset, n = 15L)
   Employee Year Performance Prior.Yr.Promo
1     33816    1  -0.2595749              0
2     34863    1   0.2056441              0
3     34863    2   0.2056441              0
4     34863    3   0.2056441              0
5     34863    4   0.2056441              1
6     34863    5   0.2056441              0
7     34863    6  -0.5467337              0
8     34863    7  -0.2595749              0
9     34863    8   0.3837042              0
10    34863    9   0.2056441              0
11    34863   10   0.2056441              0
12    34863   11   1.8884600              0
13    40806    1  -1.0119527              0
14    40806    2  -2.6229879              0
15    40881    1   0.2056441              0`

I have been running the following models:
`nullmod <- lmer(Performance ~ Prior.Yr.Promo + (1|Employee), dataset, REML = F)`
(Employee intercepts allowed to vary, fixed effect of prior year promo)

`fullmod <- lmer(Performance ~ Prior.Yr.Promo + (1 + Prior.Yr.Promo|Employee), dataset, REML = F)`
(Employee intercepts allowed to vary, and the effect (slope) of prior year promo allowed to vary by Employee)

`summary(fullmod)`

`Random effects:
 Groups     Name           Variance Std.Dev. Corr 
 employeeid (Intercept)    0.27277  0.5223

            prior.yr.promo 0.05761  0.2400   -1.00
 Residual                  0.43670  0.6608

Number of obs: 227163, groups:  employeeid, 84405`

`Fixed effects:
                Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)    -0.048490   0.002430 -19.956
prior.yr.promo -0.031239   0.005195  -6.014`

`Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr)
prir.yr.prm -0.296`

`> anova(nullmod, fullmod) 
        Df    AIC    BIC  logLik deviance  Chisq Chi Df Pr(>Chisq)

nullmod  4 530983 531024 -265487   530975

fullmod  6 529642 529704 -264815   529630 1344.5  2     < 0.00001 ***`

Theoretically, I do expect that the effect of prior year promotion on performance will differ between employees, but I'm not sure it makes sense statistically to model it that way, since the correlation between random effects is -1. I'm not sure whether that means that the model is overfit, or whether the correlation is just an artifact of prior year promotion having only two levels. I'm looking for advice about what that correlation means and whether it's statistically "wrong" to model the data with a random slope (1 + prior.yr.promo|Employee).